# SSL certificate Error. IBM API Microgateway

Tags: api, ssl-certificate, gateway

I have a node.js server on which I am running a microgateway using https. I am using a specific port. When i hit the url of the api gateway it produces a warning about the SSL certificate, After i accept the certificate it gives the error

"{"name":"PreFlowError","message":"unable to process the request"}"

API gateway is configured correctly as well as API.

what is the problem particularly ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error from your microgateway.

Verify logs at ˜/.apiconnect folder or enable a trace to catch your real problem.